# Property [SpecialtyName] not found

Tags: java, hibernate

I have facing this issue `Property [SpecialtyName] not found` but I'm sure that my model is correct and have this Property `SpecialtyName`
what exactly is gone on, is't a problem in the server or what ?

My Specialty Entity is looks like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
@Column(name="idSpecialty")
private int idSpecialty;

@Column(name="specialtyTitle")
private String specialtyTitle;

@Column(name="SpecialtyName")
public String SpecialtyName;

@Column(name="numberOfSeats")
private int numberOfSeats;


@Column(name="numberOfSeatsTemporary")
private int numberOfSeatsTemporary;


@ManyToOne( cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="Admin_idAdmin")
private Admin admin;

// getters and setters contain getSpecialtyName and setSpecialtyName
```

Comment: are you sure the column `@Column(name="SpecialtyName")` is correct?

Comment: yes is correct , is like the field in the database

Comment: Your other column names starts with a lowercase letter, does your "SpecialtyName" do the same? For some databases, case matters.

Comment: Post the exception stack trace.

Comment: @ Roger Gustavsson, Thanks man, it's exactly the solution, I have fixed it.